# mod_rewrite recursive index.html loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a virtual server with this configuration in order to redirect root requests to a specific index.php placed in a subfolder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteRule ^$ /applications/container/index.php [NC,L]
```

but when I request http://192.168.0.2 what I get is this:

http://192.168.0.2/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/

any hints?

Comment: There are no other rules? Not even inside `/var/www/html/**/.htaccess` file?

Comment: Nope! Apparently this happens even without the rewriterule! I was sure it was due to that, but I was wrong

Comment: Any other VHosts file defined for the same doc root?